# Android toast displaying incorrect String value

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin, android-toast

When setting a switch as off the user should receive a toast saying "alarm set for 00.40" for example, but for some reason the "alarm set for" has been swapped out for a string of numbers as below.

[image]

The code:

```
            override fun setSwitchOn(alarm: Alarm) {
            val toastTime = formatTime(alarm)
            val alarmManager = AlarmManager(
                alarm.id,
                alarm.hour,
                alarm.minute,
                true,
                alarm.repeat,
            )
            alarmManager.cancel(requireContext())
            Toast.makeText(
                context,
                "${R.string.toast_alarm_set} $toastTime",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
        }

        override fun setSwitchOff(alarm: Alarm) {
            val alarmManager = AlarmManager(
                alarm.id,
                alarm.hour,
                alarm.minute,
                true,
                alarm.repeat,
            )
            alarmManager.cancel(requireContext())
            Toast.makeText(context, R.string.toast_alarm_cancelled, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    })
```

and the string resources:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">App</string>

    // home screen

    <string name="next_alarm">Next Alarm</string>
    <string name="daily_alarm">Daily</string>
    <string name="once_alarm">Once</string>
    <string name="title_delete">Delete Alarm?</string>
    <string name="delete_builder_delete">Delete</string>
    <string name="delete_builder_alarm_deleted">Alarm Deleted</string>
    <!--    this line below -->
    <string name="toast_alarm_set">Alarm set for</string>
```

all others work perfectly, and changing the content of the string here does nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use string resources inside a string literal like

```kotlin
val mystr = "${R.string.somestring} days"
```

you have to actually call `getString` there to get the string (`R.string.somestring` is just an integer resource ID). It should look like this

```kotlin
val mystr = "${context.getString(R.string.somestring)} days"
```

or in your case

```kotlin
"${context.getString(R.string.toast_alarm_set)} $toastTime"
```

If you pass an integer string resource ID to a toast directly (like you do with the alarm cancelled case) it automatically calls `getString` internally, but if you pass in a string it does not do any transformations, so you have to do that yourself.

Comment: Perfect, although it says that context is non nullable, so needs either ? or !! if you wanna add that for future users.

Comment: That is a detail that depends entirely on the preceding code... If you put `val context = requireContext()` somewhere beforehand then those would not be needed in a Fragment. In an Activity you can just use `getString` directly.

Comment: You can also just do `requireContext().getString(...)` - either way, the `.?` is a Kotlin detail that is true any time you use a nullable value.